# define function then use it as callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-callback

I want to make scroller/slider - I have div's with images covering the whole screen and I want to scroll to them one by one and then get back to the first one.

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and jQuery so I'm aware that it might be a bad approach, but please take a look at this code:

I define a function:

```
$.slidestuff = function()
{
 $(document).ready(function() { 

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".slide1").offset().top 
}, 2000, 'easeInOutBack').delay(3000);

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".slide2").offset().top 
}, 2000, 'easeInOutBack').delay(3000);

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".slide3").offset().top 
}, 2000, 'easeInOutBack').delay(3000);

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".slide1").offset().top 
}, 2000, 'easeInOutBack').delay(3000);
})
}
```

And then I want to use this function as a callback at the very end of the same code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".slide1").offset().top 
}, 2000, 'easeInOutBack').delay(3000);

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".slide2").offset().top 
}, 2000, 'easeInOutBack').delay(3000);

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".slide3").offset().top 
}, 2000, 'easeInOutBack').delay(3000);

 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".slide1").offset().top 
}, 2000, 'easeInOutBack').delay(3000, slidestuff);
})
```

The second code alone (without the callback) works nice, but obviously stops - and when I use one after another, nothing happens. Help highly appreciated!

Comment: `slidestuff` is not the same as `$.slidestuff`, you're referencing something completely different ?

Comment: So should I write it as: .delay(3000, $.slidestuff) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it performs the actions only once and stops.

Comment: Do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/fP6fn/

Comment: Huge thnx adeneo! Works like a miracle!